# Detect that a PopupMenu is closed on API level 11

Tags: android, popupmenu

I have this [PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html#dismiss%28%29) in my application and would like to know when it is closed.
With API14+ this is easy when adding a dismiss listener with `setOnDismissListener()`.
But, I need to know when the PopupMenu is closed from API11+, so I cannot use the listener and need an alternative for the listener.

This I have tried already to:

- override the `dismiss()` method of the PopupMenu, but it is not called when it is closed.
- use the `PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener`, but it is not activated when the user clicked outside the menu (to close it) or clicks 'back'.

I do not have any other ideas to detect that the menu was closed. So I am hoping that someone else has a clever trick. Otherwise I cannot use PopupMenu...

Comment: A bit hacky, but can you set an `OnFocusChangeListener` from the underlying view or viewgroup? I'm not sure if it'll fire, to be honest, but it's the first thing I can think of. Other than that, you could listen at 3 points(menuItemClick, back button, onTouch of contentView), but I'm sure there's got to be something better than that.

Comment: @Geobits Thanks for your idea (I had not thought of it). But using the `OnFocusChangeListener` unfortunately is not working. I only have a View (on which I draw my UI), and it does not seem that it ever gets the focus (or loses) it...

Answer (score 1):

You can try to override method

```
public void onCloseMenu(MenuBuilder menu, boolean allMenusAreClosing)
```

of `PopupMenu` class. Exactly this method is calling `setOnDismissListener()` internally in API 14+. But this is not easy to do. Problem is what class `com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder` is not included to Android SDK, so you will not be able to compile your code if you will trying to import this class.

However, you can create your own "fake" implementation of this class, place it in package `com.android.internal.view.menu`, make a `.jar` file with it, copy this "fake library" to `libs` folder and set scope of this library in Project Settings of IntelliJ IDEA as "provided". This means that classes in this `jar` file already have real devices (what is true) and you only need them to compile your code. Main idea here - your fake `MenuBuilder` should be in classpath for `javac` compilation, but should **not** be included in resulting `.apk` file.

This is not easy solution, but it should work.

Comment: Thank you for your idea! It could provide a solution to my problem, I think. I have created the fake implementation for `MenuBuilder` (nice idea!), but I cannot find the scope setting (it is Maven specific? I do not use Maven), could you point out where I should find it? Furthermore, the `onCloseMenu()` method cannot be overridden, or so it seems. Removing the `@Override` annotation solves this problem, but I get the warning that it is never used. So I suppose it does not work? Any additional details are very welcome!

Comment: After some more testing, I works on my API14+ device, but not iwith an API11 device (for which this should provide a solution). Could it be the case that API11 does not have the `onCloseMenu()` method either, so it is not being called?

Comment: You can configure "scope" for libraries at least in IntelliJ IDEA. I think something similar should be possible to accomplish using Ant or Maven builds, by I didn't tried this yet.

Comment: I've done such test: using reflection, print all methods of class `PopupMenu` to log and run it on API 11 emulator - it prints method `onCloseMenu()`. So, I think this method is present in API 11 version of `PopupMenu` class. I still think solution should work if you configure your build correctly. Main point - your fake `MenuBuilder` should be in classpath for javac compilation, but should *not* be included in resulting `.apk`

Comment: I tried again, it works for API14, but it is not for API11. When I used reflection, it indeed shows the `onCloseMenu()` method. I made sure that I use exactly the same parameters, but my method does not get called... When I modify the name of my method, it becomes visible with reflection, so I do seem to be overriding the correct method (as it does not show both the original and my method). I do not know what else I can try to use your idea... :(

Comment: It's bad that we can't get source code of API level 11 :( It's strange that `onCloseMenu()` method is presented in api 11, but not being called, very strange. But I have no more ideas about that, sorry